# cv.glmnet, minimal MSEis higher than OLS MSE

Tags: r, cross-validation, glmnet, mse

I have a data with multicollinearity.
I can't exclude the correlated variable as they are my variable of interest.
I therefore Used Ridge regression, and tried to find optimal lambda with CV.

I face two problems that I assume that has the same reason:

1. In very small lambdas my CV plot is totally flat.
2. OLS mse is lower than mse derived from lambda.min.

mse for OLS calculated as follow:

```
     mean(lm(y~x)$residuals^2)
     [1] 0.001624517
```

Minimal mse from cv:

```
     lamda<-10^(seq(from=-20,to=2,by=0.1))
     cv.out<-cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0,standardize=T, lambda=lamda,thresh = 1e-10)
     min(cv.out$cvm)

     [1] 0.002089685
```

when I remove the "thresh = 1e-10", I get even higher mse(and higher lambdas).

What am I missing?

Comment: You right, but results remain when  I use standardization=F.

I doubled checked it and I use cv.glmnet.

Comment: You are comparing in-sample results of OLS with cross-validation results of elastic net, which does not make much sense.

Comment: I don't remember the reference but as far as I remember there is a theorem that shows, that there is always a lambda>0 which has lower mse than with lambda=0 .
That what gives this U shape of the mse in the cv plot.

Since the initial OLS mse is very small, I'm looking at very small lambdas.
I believe that my problem is that my lambdas are so small that R have difficulties with estimating it. though I tried using the `thresh=1e-10` for example.
is there any workaround?